# Issue granting permissions with Azure App Registration to Office 365 Management API

Tags: azure, api, permissions

I have a new Office 365 / Azure tenant and we have set up an Azure App for use with some security software.

In adding the App permissions, I have 2 that are not applying or granting and I am not sure why.

They are:

- ActivityReports.Read Application Type
- ThreatIntelligence.Read Application Type

The error I get is `Not granted for <Tenant>`

[image]

Would anyone know why I am getting this, have we missed enabling something in the tenant or have a missing permission perhaps?

Comment: It looks like the same permissions are in the list twice? Could it just be UI bug? Have you tried a forced refresh with Ctrl+F5?

Comment: Hi junnas, thank you for the information. I think you are correct, there looks to be a bug in the portal as the same permission is attempting to apply twice. I have removed the conflicting one and will now test. I am pretty sure this is the issue but will report back. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to click the `Grant admin consent` button, make sure your account has the permission, e.g. `Global admin` in your tenant.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. You will see in the image that it has granted for most of the permissions but not the 2 listed. I am wondering why just these 2 are missing and are not granting. Can you think of anything? I am Global Admin, 3 Global admins have attempted to grant these permissions but to no avail. Thanks again

Comment: @Alan As mentioned in juunas's comment, the two permissions look like be added twice, could you try to delete them and add again, then click the button?

Comment: Hi Joy, thank you for the information. I think you are correct along with junnas, there looks to be a bug in the portal as the same permission is attempting to apply twice. I have removed the conflicting one and will now test. I am pretty sure this is the issue but will report back. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, it does indeed